# Showing a holomorphic function is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $h$ be a holomorphic function on the open unit disk $\Delta$. Assume that there exists $\delta \in (0,1)$ such that for any $r$ with $0 \lt r \lt \delta$, $h$ satisfies:

$$|h(0)| = 1/{2\pi} \int_0 ^{2\pi} |h(re^{i\theta})|d\theta$$

How do you show that $h$ is a constant function?

I figure that the easiest way is to somehow show that $h'=0$ since that plus it being holomorphic would imply constant, however, I can't see how the given information to show that either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $r$ and recall Cauchy's formula
$$
h(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}h(re^{i\theta})d\theta.
$$
It follwows from the assumption that
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}|h(re^{i\theta})|d\theta =|\int_0^{2\pi}h(re^{i\theta})d\theta |.
$$
This equality case (since the integrand is continuous) means that there exists a real number$\alpha_r$ such that
$$
h(re^{i\theta})=e^{i\alpha_r}|h(re^{i\theta})|
$$
for all $\theta$.

Plugging this back in the Cauchy Formula and using the assumption again, we get:
$$
h(0)=e^{i\alpha_r}|h(0)|.
$$

So $\alpha_r=\alpha$ does not depend on $r$ and the function
$$
e^{-i\alpha}h
$$
is holomorphic and nonnegative on the open disk of radius $\delta$ centered at $0$.

It follows that $e^{-i\alpha}h$, hence $h$ is constant.

Comment: @DavidM Did this help? If not, I can expand if you want.

Comment: Yes, it was very helpful, just one thing I don't have so clear: why can we say that $e^{-i\alpha}h$ is constant?

Comment: If a holomorphic function is nonnegative, then $\overline{f(z)}=f(z)$. This is only possible if $f$ is constant (on the connected component of its domain). If it were not, write it as a power series. Take the conjugate. You will have terms of the form $\bar{z}^n$, which contradict holomorphy.

Comment: I see it now, thank you for your explanations!